# How to : add comments on old questions ? and, reopening closed questions?

Tags: support, specific-question

My question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411987/collatz-like-5-x-pm-1-3 has been closed as "not a real question". I agree the question was insufficiently definite, and am grateful to the moderators and commenters (and to the person who added good math formatting to my post).

Actually rather than pose a new question, I had wished to  introduce the *5n±1/3* Collatz-like function as a *sub-comment* under user *Quanta*'s own, at question [The $5n+1$ Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14569/the-5n1-problem)

I could not find *how* to add my comment there however! I can see links/buttons to "*edit*" and to "*reply*", nothing to "*add*" a comment ! Is it really impossible to add new comments to the discussion at (non closed) questions, maybe, after some determined time, or am I just too dumb & missing something ?

I still am of the opinion than my variant has special "merits" beyond being one of an infinite class of Collatz-like iterations. I'd be glad if you helped me find the most proper way to have it introduced and discussed.

If it is not possible to add a short comment under *Quanta*'s at the question mentioned above, then alternatively am I allowed to try to reformulate my closed "question" so it is shorter and avoids the *vagueness* criterion ? How am I supposed to submit a question so revised ?

Comment: User having less than 50 reputation points can only comment on their one posts, see [privileges](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Aha! Yet commenting seems most appropriate a way for adding information to, or asking clarification about a previous comment by another user. Doing so as if in answer to the original Question does not seem to be a proper option, does it ? What options are staying open, chat is it ?

Comment: What to do if you want to comment and you do not have sufficient rep? You can post it as an answer; which will probably be deleted by a moderator and converted to a comment. (You can explicitly mention that you are posting an answer because you do not have sufficient rep to comment.) See help on [deleted answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/deleted-answers). IMHO a better solution would be trying to earn some reputation points, so that you can comment; if you can think of some way to earn rep.

Comment: The software is telling you NOT to add your question as a comment to another question.  (Instead, improve your own closed question.)  The reason for the limitation on comments is exactly this: new users often want to use comments inappropriately before they understand the workings of the site (and other stackexchange sites).

Answer (score 6):

> [A]m I allowed to try to reformulate my closed "question" so it is shorter and avoids the vagueness criterion?

Yes. From the [Help Center | Closed Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/closed-questions):

> Closed questions cannot be answered, but are eligible for improvement (and eventual re-opening) through editing, voting, and commenting. See How to Ask for guidance on editing your question to improve it.

Another topic in [Help Center | Reopen Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions) is also relevant.

---

> I had wished to introduce the $5n\pm 1/3$ Collatz-like function as a sub-comment

Introducing questions as comments is not effective (hardly anyone will notice) and may even be considered as an inappropriate use of the site. Inexperienced users are blocked from adding comment on posts other than their own, partly to prevent them from making such mistakes.

Comment: I guess this post is also worth mentioning when talking about reopening questions: [Requests for Reopen Votes](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes).

Comment: @user79365 : "Introducing questions as comments is not effective..." Probably not. But please notice that the discussion we are having stems from my desire to introduce a (set of) problems, which (by moderator judgement) has been deemed _NOT a question_ ! Hence, a comment. But I'm barred from adding _comments_, is this not what in English they call a catch-2-2 situation ?

Comment: @NimbUs: What do you mean by "by moderator judgement"?  Moderators are distinguished by diamonds next to their user names (see mine at the end of this comment).  No moderators were involved in the closing of your question, only users [with sufficient privilege](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @A.Fischer : my bad then, I misused the word moderator, having in mind such users _with sufficient privilege_ as are permitted to close - or is it, request closure ? Never mind...